# Prevent Debian from auto-assembling RAID at boot

Tags: debian, startup, raid, initramfs

I set up a Debian wheezy (7.6), installed openmediavault, and created a software RAID 5 with that. It is listed at `/dev/md127`.
Now I want to move that to a virtual XEN VM. To do so, I have to stop Debian to automatically assemble the RAID at startup, so I can put it through to the VM via `xm block-attach`, and I don't get that to work. No matter what I try, there is still `md127` listed under `/dev/`, and after every boot I can manually end it via `mdadm --stop /dev/md127`. But even after that, it is still listed under `/dev/`.

What I already tried:

- `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`: commented out array line:

  ```
  #ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=masterbox:MainRaid UUID=3f620e6d:4e655d66:b931eb71:baf7cf3a  
  ARRAY /dev/md0 name=Null
  ```
- moved `/libs/udev/rules.d/64-md-raid.rules` to `/root/`
- `update-initramfs u`
- commented out the line in `/etc/fstab`
- disassembled RAID manually via `mdadm --stop /dev/md127`
- set kernel parameter `raid=noautodetect` in `/etc/default/grub`:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet raid=noautodetect"
  ```
- rebooted
- disabled mdadm services at boot

Here's also the log from dmesg:

```
[    3.448121] md: md127 stopped.
[    3.452518] md: bind<sda>
[    3.452747] md: bind<sdc>
[    3.452933] md: bind<sdb>

[    3.954794] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[    3.954797] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[    3.954799] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
[    3.955417] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
[    3.955436] md/raid:md127: device sdb operational as raid disk 0
[    3.955439] md/raid:md127: device sdc operational as raid disk 2
[    3.955442] md/raid:md127: device sda operational as raid disk 1
[    3.955740] md/raid:md127: allocated 3228kB
[    3.955988] md/raid:md127: raid level 5 active with 3 out of 3 devices, algorithm 2
[    3.955991] RAID conf printout:
[    3.955993]  --- level:5 rd:3 wd:3
[    3.955996]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdb
[    3.955999]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sda
[    3.956000]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdc
[    3.956044] md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 6000916561920
```

... How can I bring Debian to not touch the RAID drives *at all*, so I can pass them to my VM?

Comment: Uninstall `mdadm` from dom0? Unfortunately that assumes dom0 doesn't need any other RAID devices though.

Comment: @Celada: Yeah, I did this now and it solves my problem. Though it is of course not the best solution :p

Comment: Why don't you just pass the already assembled raid array to the domU instead of the individual disks?

Comment: Well, I wanted to let the NAS-Software in the VM to manage everything - from assembling drives to a raid, to assigning and sharing filesystems. The root-OS was supposed to really only host the VMs, and nothing more. Of course that would have been at least a simple solution. Sadly I cannot try it anymore, as I have re-installed my entire homeserver to a no-virtualization-solution.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but since I searched quite long for a solution, I want to share my result:

```
# /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
ARRAY <ignore> UUID=3f620e6d:4e655d66:b931eb71:baf7cf3a
```

From [`man mdadm.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/mdadm.conf.5.html):

> `ARRAY`
>
>   The  ARRAY  lines identify actual arrays.  The second word on the line may be the name of the device where the array
>                   is normally assembled, such as
>   `/dev/md1`
>   or
>   `/dev/md/backup`
>   .  If the name does not start with a  slash  (
>   **'`/`'**
>   ),  it  is
>                   treated  as  being  in
>   `/dev/md/`
>   .  Alternately the word
>   `<ignore>`
>   (complete with angle brackets) can be given in which
>                   case any array which matches the rest of the line will never be automatically  assembled.  If  no  device  name  is
>                   given,
>   `mdadm`
>   will use various heuristics to determine an appropriate name.

Comment: Thx! I am using my installation without virtualization since then, but maybe I find the time to try the XEN approach again with your tip. Will update this post then.

Comment: Also I read somewhere here that `AUTO -all` in `mdadm.conf` stops auto-assembling, but the whole file will be ignored, if it does not include an `ARRAY` line. So in order to ignore all arrays add `ARRAY <ignore> UUID=00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000` and `AUTO -all` to `mdadm.conf` (not tested).

Comment: @Toxiro It does work, see Slawomir's answer, and I've double-checked it on Debian 9.6.

Answer (score 4):

You said you disabled the `mdadm` service, but that service runs the monitoring deamon; there's a separate `mdadm-raid` service that starts all md arrays in userland based on the configuration file. And, you can also run `dpkg-reconfigure mdadm` to disable auto-starting arrays.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 18.04, this worked (append it to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`):

```
AUTO -all
ARRAY <ignore> UUID=00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000
```

Nothing was auto-assembled after that point.

Comment: This also works on Debian 9.6.

Answer (score 1):

I found removing udev rules for mdadm raid-assembly was the only thing that worked:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/64-md-raid-assembly.rules
```

Maybe move it to home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I realized if you delete `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` (or `/etc/mdadm.conf`) and if you have the mount entry in `etc/fstab` new mdadm.conf gets created automatically.

I put `#` and commented out `fstab` and `mdadm.conf` entry without deleting .conf file.

It stopped auto assembling array and automounting.

Comment: Since th OP said that they "commented out the line in /etc/fstab" I guess the main difference here is that you also commented out the entry from mdadm.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that situation on TrueNAS SCALE and OpenMediaVault, which both build on Debian by removing every file md* inside

```
ls -R /usr/share/initramfs-tools/*|grep ^md
```

and update the init

```
update-initramfs -u
```

and now no more time waiting for mdadm which randomly mount raid's

ps: I also took the time to remove every file which was pointed at **btrfs, dm, lvm, ntfs, xfs** without any issue

my Debian boot superfast now :)

Comment: That works fine, but you do not need to delete the files (just in case you want to restore the functionality later), you can simple remove the executable bit: `chmod -x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/{hooks,scripts/local-block,scripts/local-bottom}/mdadm`

Answer (score 0):

Previously it was mentioned that removing `/lib/udev/rules.d/64-md-raid-assembly.rules` could help. I looked up the contents of file and seems it will be enough to add two kernel cmdline parameters: `noiswmd` and `nodmraid`.

```
# "noiswmd" on kernel command line stops mdadm from handling
#  "isw" (aka IMSM - Intel RAID).
# "nodmraid" on kernel command line stops mdadm from handling
#  "isw" or "ddf".
IMPORT{cmdline}="noiswmd"
IMPORT{cmdline}="nodmraid"

ENV{nodmraid}=="?*", GOTO="md_inc_end"
ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="ddf_raid_member", GOTO="md_inc"
ENV{noiswmd}=="?*", GOTO="md_inc_end"
ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="isw_raid_member", GOTO="md_inc"
GOTO="md_inc_end"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/439535)